# Wrap TinyMCE 'table' in div''

Tags: php, html, wordpress, tinymce, advanced-custom-fields

Is there a way to wrap a `<table>` in a div with TinyMCE?

Preferably something natively by extending TinyMCE, I know I can get it to work with pure JS.

I was attempting to do something like this with no luck. (by following this doc: https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/configure/content-formatting/#formatparameters)
But I can't seem to even get this to work:

```
$settings['formats'] = json_encode([
...
     "table" => [
            [
                "selector" => "table",
                "classes" => "test"
            ]
        ]
...
])
```

Ultimately I'd like to see the HTML output on the client side as:

```
<div class="my_class">
     <table> 
     ... 
     </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, did u figure out a solution to this? I have the same problem

Comment: Unfortunately, no 

Comment: Same here. Couldnt find a way to extend it natively with TinyMCE, so I ended up using regex before outputting in my React component:
`const editorContent = editorState.replace(/<table[^>]*>[\s\S]*?<\/table>/g, '<div class="et-core-editorcontent_table">$&</div>')`

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want this type of behavior to set a horizontal scroll onto the table.

If that was the case then here's what you can do.

```
<div class="w-[200px] overflow-hidden">
  <!-- 
    # Hack: Apply styles directly on the table.

    .table {
      display: block;
      overflow: auto;
    }
   -->
  <table class="table">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>+xx xxxxxxxxxx</td>
        <td>+xx xxxxxxxxxx</td>
        <td>+xx xxxxxxxxxx</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```